# Laravel - oneToMany returning Undefined property

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I just searched for this problem in all posts but i cant get the answer.

I have 3 tables: users | categorys | sectors with the below model:

> User.php

```
public function categorys(){
        return $this->hasMany('Category');
}
```

> Category.php

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
public function sectors(){
    return $this->hasMany('Sector');
}
```

> Sector.php

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

> Tables

- users:

  - id,name
- categorys:

  - id,name,user_id(fk)
- sectors:

  - id,name,category_id(fk)

I want to print in a view all the sectors from authenticated user, with something like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user = Auth::user(); 
$sectors = $user->categorys->sectors;
```

and use this in $sectors variable in view

```
@foreach($sectors as $sector)
  {{ $sector->id }}
  {{ $sector->name }}
@endforeach
```

But i get this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$sectors
```

Need help! Thanks

BR

Comment: Try harder, There are at least a few questions here on SO covering this issue. And, you have `hasManyThrough` relation for this case. And, did you specify `table` on the `Category` model? Since `categories` is the default, that Eloquent will be searching for.

Comment: Yes i specified the table's name to 'categorys'

Comment: i found the solution.

As Jarek Tkaczyk said, there is the hasManyThrough. Use it in User model

`public function sectors(){
 return $this->hasManyThrough('Sector','Category');
}`

and in the controller view use:

` $sectors = $user->sectors; `

Thanks for helping

Comment: instead of use: `$sectors = $user->categorys->sectors;`

use: `$sectors->load('categorys.sectors');`

Comment: Hi again,

Since i fixed the previous issue, i have another one. 
Imagine that i have a 4º table (costs, with a sector_id ) wicth belongs to sectors table. 
How can i get all costs from one user id?

i tried the `return $this->hasManyThrough('Cost', 'Sector','Category);` in User.php for `function costs()` but i cant retrieve any needed info.

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned before here is the answer for the above issue.
The hasmanythought relation is the correct way to relate and easy query thouse 3 tables.

> For model User.php you need to create the relationship:

```
public function sectors(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Sector','Category');
}
```

> Now in your controller you need to do:

```
$user = new User;
$user = Auth::user(); 
$sectors = $user->sectors;
#return the view showsectors
return View::make('showsectors')->with('sectors', $sectors);
```

Use this variable (sectors) to print the query result (**all sector's descriptions from one user**) in your view, with something like the below:

```
@foreach($sectors as $sector)
 {{ $sector->id }}
 {{ $sector->description }}
@endforeach
```

Thanks for helping with this.

BR

Answer (score 0):

Either you forgot to mention it in your article, or the `sector_id` field is missing in the `categorys` table.

According to your database structure there is no foreign key from table `categorys` to table `sectors`